# Print path of an object in current working directory using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a requirement in which i have to specify a file path of an object (say 'abcd.jpg'). I am able to find the path with os module in python. But it contains '\\' as a separator. How to convert this separator to '\'.

```
>>> import os
>>> a = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'abcd.jpg'
>>> a
'C:\\Python27\\abcd.jpg'
```

In my script i am only allowed to write the path name as 'C:\Python27\abcd.jpg'

Comment: That's the `repr` of the string... you don't actually have two slashes in your string... use `print a`...

Comment: print(a) gives correct output . But i want to use variable in following way:         s = 'This is path %s' %a

Comment: Even when you are using in that way when you do `print s` you will get the correct output. The representation of a string contains escape characters and many other things. But when it is printed you get the correct result

Comment: Also use `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'abcd.jpg')` or rather `os.path.abspath('abcd.jpg')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `print a` and you should be fine. What you are doing is actually the `repr` of the string.

Comment: print(a) gives correct output . But i want to use variable in following way:     b = 'This is path %s' %a

Comment: @user3501405 yes, and **printing `b`** will give your desired output.

Comment: Then as long as you `print(b)` that should give you the correct output.